# Vue - using v-model on a <component> with :is

Tags: vue.js, components

Is there a way in Vue to use `v-model` on a `<component>` whose tag is specified by `:is='tag'` (where `tag` obviously resolves to "input")?

This doesn't work, i.e. the input does not contain the starting value "init".

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const tag = 'input'
    const bar = ref('init')
    return { tag, bar }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <component :is='tag' v-model='bar' />
</template>
```

This works, obviously, but can I do this with a dynamic tag name?

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const bar = ref('init')
    return { bar }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model='bar' />
</template>
```

[**Demo**](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__eNp9UttugzAM/RUvL2mlQlQeEa00bdov7CUvFExLB0mUmHZS1X+fgZX1pkUowjnOsX1OTuLVufjQoUhFFgpfO1prU7fOeoITeKzgDJW3LUhOktrg9wCVWOVdwynaaApInZvN+wB4FdYEAsq3sAJZG9cR3/sDNrlngJlnDNYk53dg8gz1XMIb7ohpF33WsCVw7mHe+MvU1D8HhK1rckKOALLdcr1M4dP6r5ApDoZDt/6osSnBWdf1qWWm3IgMTcMham2JzUpyJQlqYkpSeLcYjCQ4MuMjobH0hLSwrKpBQ5DWYSV5EHlTIhlrZGpqXSzE6ETU5i7eB2vYpUFk/QsELdKL7FqwQ32sxY7IhVSpUBW9t/sQW79V/Bf7zlDdYoyhjTbeHgN6JtZiccWh+PCAPvJoSvTo/+O8S33gvdjDo7zx/JeXduvOKBBAZe3LtAZk0O5KkcHayebHt8gT3DwFcf4BgiL1pg==)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-model` syntaxic sugar is treated differently whether you use it on a Vue component or a native html tag.

When used on a **component**, `<MyInput v-model="msg" />` is equivalent of using
`<MyInput :value="msg" @update:value="val => msg = val" />`.

When used on an **`<input>` tag**, it's translated like this:
`<input :value="msg" @input="evt => msg = evt.target.value" />`.

When using dynamic component `<component :is="" />`, Vue mostly assume it's gonna be Vue components, so it will bind the event `@update:value`, which isn't triggerred by the `<input>` element, and thus won't update your binded variable.

Here, you should break down the `v-model` into the prop + event, like on the native `input` tag:

```
<component :is="tag" :value="bar" @input="evt => bar = evt.target.value" />
```